# Trying to put if else condition to a column in a Dataframe but getting Keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a big dataset. One column is price column. I am trying to round the value of price column with this following code:

```
for i in range(0,len(df5['price'])):
    if df5['price'][i]>=0 and df5['price'][i]<=50:
        df5['price'][i] = 50
    elif df5['price'][i]>50 and df5['price'][i] <= 100:
        df5['price'][i] = 100
    elif df5['price'][i]>100 and df5['price'][i]<=150:
        df5['price'][i]=150
    elif df5['price'][i]>150 and df5['price'][i]<=200:
        df5['price'][i]=200
    elif df5['price'][i]>200 and df5['price'][i]<=250:
        df5['price'][i]=250
    elif df5['price'][i]>250 and df5['price'][i]<=300:
        df5['price'][i]=300
    elif df5['price'][i]>300 and df5['price'][i]<=350:
        df5['price'][i]=350
    elif df5['price'][i]>350 and df5['price'][i]<=400:
        df5['price'][i]=400
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-218-4872943ca532> in <module>
      1 for i in range(0,len(df5['price'])):
----> 2     if df5['price'][i]>=0 and df5['price'][i]<=50:
      3         df5['price'][i] = 50
      4     elif df5['price'][i]>50 and df5['price'][i] <= 100:
      5         df5['price'][i] = 100

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 35
```

What is wrong here? Can anybody explain please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use a loop for this, `apply()` will be much better.

Comment: Use `df['price'] // 50 * 50 + 50`

Comment: Also, you haven't shared a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to round values in the `price` column up to the nearest 50, you can also try this:

```
import numpy as np

df5['price'] = df5.price.apply(lambda val: np.ceil(val/50)*50)
```

Comment: p.s. this solution is slower than Bishwarup Bhattacharjee's, might not be optimal is the dataset is really big.

Comment: Is the `apply()` even necessary here? I'm pretty sure @Erfan's suggestion of `df['price'] // 50 * 50 + 50` is better.

Comment: @AMC, yeah, Erfan's suggestion is definitely better. I'm new to answering questions, so can you please help me a bit? What's the best practice in this case? Should I modify, delete my answer or leave it as it is?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't run a loop over pandas DataFrame, even if that works it would be painfully slow. If you must, then use `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows` method which is much faster than a loop but would still be pretty slow nonetheless.

For your problem assuming the bucket is equispaced you can do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

df5['price'] = (np.digitize(df5.price, np.arange(0, 450, 50)))*50
```

To answer your question why you get the `KeyError` is perhaps because of the fact that your dataframe indexes are off. Consider changing `df5['price'][i]` to `df5['price'].iloc[i]`